# ObservableProperty doesn't update after program start

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

In my program the binding does not update my image source.

ImageDataModel:

```
public class ImageDataModel
{
    public string EngineNumber { get; set; }
    public string ImageNumber { get; set; }
    public string EvaluationStatus { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

EngineViewModel:

```
public partial class EngineViewModel:ObservableObject {
    private readonly AppPreferences prefs = new();
    private readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    
    public ObservableCollection<ImageDataModel> ImageList { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler<string> MessageReceived;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public List<ImageDataModel> imageData;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public ImageDataModel selectedItem;
    
    public EngineViewModel() {
        ImageList = new();
    }

    public void HandleMessage(string message) {
        MessageReceived?.Invoke(this, message);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task SelectionChanged() {
        try {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedItem.FileName)) {
                SelectedItem.ImagePath = prefs.Get("images_save_location", "") + @"\" + 
                    SelectedItem.FileName;
                SelectedItem.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(SelectedItem.ImagePath);
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public async Task LoadFileNames(string engineIdentifier) {
        try {
            await MergeFiles(engineIdentifier);
            string folderPath = prefs.Get("images_save_location", "");
            string searchString = engineIdentifier;
            if(Directory.Exists(folderPath)) {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
                foreach(string filePath in files) {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    if(fileName.EndsWith("png")) {
                        string[] parts = fileName.Split('_');
                        if(parts.Length >= 7 && parts[1].Contains(searchString)) {
                            string engineNumber = parts[1];
                            string imageNumber = parts[5];
                            string evaluationStatus = parts[6].Substring(0, 
                                parts[6].IndexOf('.'));
                            ImageList.Add(new ImageDataModel {
                                EngineNumber = engineNumber,
                                ImageNumber = imageNumber,
                                EvaluationStatus = evaluationStatus,
                                FileName = fileName
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }        
        
    }

    private async Task MergeFiles(string engineIdentifier) {
        try {
            string folderPath = prefs.Get("images_save_location", "");
            string searchString = engineIdentifier;
            if(Directory.Exists(folderPath)) {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
                foreach(string filePath in files) {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    if(fileName.EndsWith("bmp") && fileName.Contains(searchString)) {
                        await Utilities.Utilities.MergeBmpAndSvg(folderPath, 
                            fileName[..^4]);
                    }
                }
            } else {

            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

EngineView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Shell.BackgroundColor="#696969"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    x:Class="EngineCheck.Views.EngineView"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EngineCheck.ViewModels">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:EngineViewModel x:Name="viewmodel"/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Grid>
            <Label Text="Motoransicht" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                TextColor="Black"
                TextTransform="Uppercase"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                FontSize="32"/>
        </Grid>
    </Shell.TitleView>

    <!--PageLayout-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8.0*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--Motor image view-->
        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="0"
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue">

            <ScrollView>
                <Frame BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="0">
                    <Image x:Name="image" 
                        Aspect="AspectFill" 
                        Source="{Binding SelectedItem.ImageSource}"
                        Background="Beige">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <PinchGestureRecognizer PinchUpdated="OnPinchUpdated"/>
                            <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="OnPanUpdated"/>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnDoubleTap"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </Frame>
            </ScrollView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>

        <!--Controls-->
        <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                               BackgroundColor="DarkCyan">

            <Button Text="Testmotor"
                    Clicked="OnTestButtonClicked"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

    <!--ImageList-->

        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}" 
                        Grid.Row="2" 
                        BackgroundColor="Bisque" 
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                        SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="11">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="{Binding EngineNumber}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding ImageNumber}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding EvaluationStatus}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
```

EngineView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class EngineView : ContentPage {
    private double _currentScale = 1;
    private double _startScale = 1;
    private double _xOffset = 0;
    private double _yOffset = 0;
    private bool _secondDoubleTapp = false;
    private TcpServerExample.TcpServer _tcpServer;
    EngineViewModel vm = new();
    readonly AppPreferences prefs = new();
    readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public EngineView() {
        InitializeComponent();
        _tcpServer = new 
        TcpServerExample.TcpServer
             (System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(prefs.Get("cam_ip_address", "")),
             Convert.ToInt32(prefs.Get("cam_port", "")), vm);
        _tcpServer.StartServerInBackgroundThread();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    
    private async void OnDoubleTap(object sender, TappedEventArgs e) {
        ...
    }

    private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e) {
        ...
    }

    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e) {
        ...
    }

    private void OnTestButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ...
    }
```

When the program is started the ImageList is still empty. Therefore nothing is displayed in the CollectionView yet. In the course of the program, a motor number is sent at some point and images with this number are placed in the ImageList.
All images that should be in there, are. But the view does not update automatically. However, if I change something in the XAML code and save it, it is regenerated and I can display the images by clicking on them in the CollectionView in the Image tag.

With every incoming motor number (sent via TCP-IP interface - works as it should) the CollectionView should be updated.  But it does not

I am using the MAUI Community Toolkit. Tried everything also manually via INotifyPropertyChanged but same result

[image]

The Testmotor Button is just to simulate incoming tcp-ip message

Comment: Is this release or debug?

Comment: Binding works with property change.... Not with "something changes inside the property"... Prolly you need observableCollection if it is a thing in maui

Comment: @H.A.H. its debug

Comment: @Selvin As I mentioned earlier, I tried both PropertyChanged and ObservableProperty and neither worked. I also tried Observable Collection.

Comment: What you have tried with observableCollection? It is not used in your xaml code... It is not even initialized

Comment: ImageList is an ObservableCollection. Its the ItemSource of the CollectionView. And its initialized iside the viewmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Everything was correct. There was a problem with the MAUI Community Toolkit. I reinstalled the nuget and everything worked as expected

UPDATE

Strangely, the bindings of the CollectionView items only work after I have clicked on each one once.
Does anyone have an idea? But if they are all clicked once I can display each of the images as many times as I want.

UPDATE 2

TcpServer

```
public class TcpServer {
    private TcpListener _listener;
    private bool _isRunning;
    private EngineViewModel _viewModel;
    private SynchronizationContext _syncContext;

    public TcpServer(IPAddress ipAddress, int port, EngineViewModel 
        viewModel) {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        _syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        _listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
    }

    public void StartServerInBackgroundThread() {
        Task.Run(() => {
            _isRunning = true;
            _listener.Start();

            while(_isRunning) {
                try {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client...");
                    TcpClient client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                    // Handle the client in a separate thread
                    Thread clientThread = new Thread(HandleClient);
                    clientThread.Start(client);
                } catch(SocketException) {
                    // Handle socket exceptions if needed
                }
            }
        });
    }

    

    public void Stop() {
        _isRunning = false;
        _listener.Stop();
    }

    private void HandleClient(object clientObj) {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)clientObj;
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        while((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 
            0) {
            string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, 
                bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Received from client: " + message);

            _syncContext.Post(state => {
                _viewModel.LoadFileNames(message, 0);
            }, null);

            // Echo the received message back to the client
            byte[] responseBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Server 
                received: " + message);
            stream.Write(responseBuffer, 0, responseBuffer.Length);
        }
        // Close the client connection when done
        stream.Close();
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

LoadFileNames is called if a engineNumber is sent to the tcp server

I forgot to add one line inside the ImageList in my viewModel class

```
ImageList.Add(new ImageDataModel 
{
    EngineNumber = engineNumber,
    ImageNumber = imageNumber,
    EvaluationStatus = evaluationStatus,
    FileName = fileName,
    ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(filePath)
});
```

Comment: This "accepted answer" should be deleted. The guy opened new question with the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77035802/binding-doesnt-change-properly-in-maui-when-i-change-it-inside-my-viewmodel

Comment: In your next question, you scrapped all the usage of CommunityToolkit.MVVM. I guess this is what happens when everything works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
<VerticalStackLayout ...>
     <ScrollView>
```

A stack of a single item.

```
<HorizontalStackLayout >
     <Button Text="Testmotor"
```

Another single item stack.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}" 
      SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}">
```

^This is the reason it loads after selecting them once.

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
```

^This plain and simple will not render in Release.

I can continue, but I hope you get the picture.

My advice is that gradually implement new code, and not try to write 10 pages at once, and try to make it working.

Everything you have is bound correctly. But you are not using it right.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I have removed the individual item stacks. But I think there is a misunderstanding. When I load an image, I have to click on all 7 items first. After that the images are loaded. If I don't click only one I can press the others as many times as I want, nothing happens.

Comment: So you want it fixed all at once. Ok. Lets start from this, where is the calling of the Task "LoadFileNames".

Comment: See my UPDATE 2

Comment: @DaveR This tcp server, holding reference to your viewmodel, starting a thread and modifying your observable collection from there, is a triple no.

Comment: Can you lease tell me what i have to change or perhaps a hint

Comment: i got it, everything was correct. I just forgot to add ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(filePath) to the List

Comment: Interesting if everything is correct and it was fixed with "reinstalling the nuget package", "add ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFIle(filePath)" and "one line inside the ImageList in my viewModel class", why this SOLVED question is followed by this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77035802/binding-doesnt-change-properly-in-maui-when-i-change-it-inside-my-viewmodel