# Binding doesnt change properly in MAUI when i change it inside my ViewModel

Tags: c#, maui

I have a function in my viewmodel in which an asynchronous method is called. To execute a loading animation in the UI I have a boolean isLoading variable as binding. Immediately before calling the asynchronous method this variable is set to true and as soon as the method is finished it is set to false again.
But it seems that the variable is not changed correctly.
Anybody got an idea?

LoadFilenames snippet

```
public async Task LoadFileNames(string engineIdentifier, int displayMode) {
try {
    ImageList.Clear();
    IsLoading = true;
    await MergeFiles(engineIdentifier);

    IsLoading = false;
    ...
```

From my ViewModel

```
private bool _isLoading;
public bool IsLoading {
    get { return _isLoading; }
    set {
        _isLoading = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null) =>
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
```

From my View

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         Shell.BackgroundColor="#696969"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:EngineCheck.Converters"
         x:Class="EngineCheck.Views.EngineView"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EngineCheck.ViewModels">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:EngineViewModel x:Name="viewmodel"/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Calling the Loading animation

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}"/>
```

All other bindings in the xaml file work smoothly. So the implementation of the ViewModel seems to be correct

UPDATE

My MergeFiles method

```
private async Task MergeFiles(string engineIdentifier) {
    try {
        string folderPath = prefs.Get("images_save_location", "");
        string searchString = engineIdentifier;
        if(Directory.Exists(folderPath)) {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
            foreach(string filePath in files) {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                if(fileName.EndsWith("bmp") && 
                    fileName.Contains(searchString)) {
                        Utilities.Utilities.MergeBmpAndSvg(folderPath, 
                            fileName[..^4]);
                    }
            }
        } else {
        //TODO
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

MergeBmpAndSvg method

```
public static void MergeBmpAndSvg(string path, string filename) {
    try {
        Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(path + "/" + filename + ".bmp");
        SvgDocument svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(path + "/" + filename +         
            ".svg");
        Bitmap svgBitmap = svgDocument.Draw();
        Bitmap resultImage = new Bitmap(bmpImage.Width, bmpImage.Height);
        using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(resultImage)) {
            graphics.DrawImage(bmpImage, 0, 0);
            graphics.DrawImage(svgBitmap, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0));
        }
        resultImage.Save(path + "/" + filename + ".png");
        bmpImage.Dispose();
        svgBitmap.Dispose();
        resultImage.Dispose();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that your Activity Indicator itself is not displayed on the screen, and the issue is not the binding

Comment: No for testing i just edit the binding with "true" and it works fine

Comment: Have you tried debugging the async method and checking if, for some reason, there's an issue in the execution? Because everything else looks good to me

Comment: No. In the async method everything looks fine. The program makes a png image from a bmp and an svg graphic. To avoid that the user see nothing i need kind of animation and block the program. 
In the following link I asked a different question but the async method is in there. But the IsLoading = true is missing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76967481/observableproperty-doesnt-update-after-program-start/76968256?noredirect=1#comment135692251_76968256

Comment: In your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76967481/observableproperty-doesnt-update-after-program-start/76968256) you're clearly using Source Generators, e.g. by applying the `[ObservableProperty]` attribute. Now, you're showing a manual implementation of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for the same ViewModel. Why is that? Have you tried using the `[ObservableProperty]` Source Generator also for your `IsLoading` property?

Comment: i changed it because i had some problems with the observableProperties and with the "standard way" with INotifyPropertyChanged my problems were solved.
But it seems that the problem is anywhere near the async Task method. When i set the IsLoading property in the contructor it works but from inside the async Task method there are some problems i think

Comment: @DaveR if you haven't written complete nonsense on your first question, then accepted that nonsense as correct answer, and then created a second question on the same problem, I would have considered answering this. Why don't you try "Reinstalling the nuget again" like you did there?

Comment: That's very strange, but you're also not showing all of the relevant code, it seems. Do any exceptions occur in the try-catch-block? Is `ImageList` initialized?

Comment: @Julian seems that the LoadFileNames method freezes the whole application. No exceptions occure

Comment: @H.A.H. because its not the problem. I tested it

Comment: @DaveR I am well aware that it is not a problem. I actually know how to use MVVM. I am telling you that the last copy of this question stays answered. And people that check for MVVM problems, read your "accepted answer", because, quoting you: "I solved it. Everything was correct. There was a problem with the MAUI Community Toolkit. I reinstalled the nuget and everything worked as expected"

Comment: Here is another thing you commented on the same quesiton: "i got it, everything was correct. I just forgot to add ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(filePath) to the List".  You keep solving it, and somehow you keep asking about the same problem.

Comment: @DaveR If the application freezes, then you may have encountered a deadlock or some other issue related to asynchronous code. What does your `MergeFiles()` do and does it ever return? And where do you actually call `LoadFileNames()`? Please show sufficient code. What you've provided at the moment is not enough to [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Julian i addeda update to my post above

Comment: @DaveR Your `MergeFiles()` method doesn't run asynchronously, it only uses blocking calls, there is no call to any `async` method that you are (or could be) `await`ing. Just marking a method as `async` and using `Task` as a return type doesn't make a method [asynchronous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). `async` and `await` always go together in the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap). Can you improve the description of the problem that you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into a deadlock by mixing asynchronous code and synchronous code.

The following code does **not** run asynchronously, there are only synchronous (blocking) calls and nothing is being `await`ed:

```cs
private async Task MergeFiles(string engineIdentifier) {
    try {
        string folderPath = prefs.Get("images_save_location", "");
        string searchString = engineIdentifier;
        if(Directory.Exists(folderPath)) {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
            foreach(string filePath in files) {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                if(fileName.EndsWith("bmp") && 
                    fileName.Contains(searchString)) {
                        Utilities.Utilities.MergeBmpAndSvg(folderPath, 
                            fileName[..^4]);
                    }
            }
        } else {
        //TODO
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

***Note:** Just marking a method as `async` and using the `Task` return type, will not make your code run asynchronously!*

In order to make the above code, which may be a longer running CPU-bound operation, run in an asynchronous fashion, you should change its signature to `void` (without `async`!):

```cs
private void MergeFiles(string engineIdentifier) {
    try {
        string folderPath = prefs.Get("images_save_location", "");
        string searchString = engineIdentifier;
        if(Directory.Exists(folderPath)) {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
            foreach(string filePath in files) {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                if(fileName.EndsWith("bmp") && 
                    fileName.Contains(searchString)) {
                        Utilities.Utilities.MergeBmpAndSvg(folderPath, 
                            fileName[..^4]);
                    }
            }
        } else {
        //TODO
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.Error(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and then move the call to that method to a thread pool thread using [`Task.Run()`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html):

```cs
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    MergeFiles(engineIdentifier);
});
```